# Routing to '/' just sends me to the login page in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I just got this project from other guy and I got this weird behaviour:

There is only one '/' in the `web.php` routing file.

It is in the auth route group

Something like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::get('/','WelcomeController@get_welcome_view');

}
```

Route auth is obviously people who are logged in.

Now I want www.mysite.com to go to welcome if you are not logged in, and to somewhere else if you are logged in.

I have tried to put another route outside of the auth middleware but it tells me that it is trying to get propety of non-object.

I guess a way to do this would be to redirect in the controller itself, but I think it is not a clean way to do it as the routing should be done in `web.php` .

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auth middleware is checking if the current user is login if not it redirects to the login page.
If you want to stop the redirection, remove the route from the auth middleware group.

```
Route::get('/','WelcomeController@get_welcome_view');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
  /*Here you will put only routes that need the user to authenticate before accessing the page*/
}
```